# Creating dictionary from tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Problem: I am trying to create a dictionary from a tuple but I get the below messages:

```
Valueerror: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 3; 2 is required
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I tried using dict() to create the dictionary and this seems to work only when the list of tuples contains two elements.

code:

```
my_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2,3), ('c',)]

dict(my_list)
```

The result I am trying to produce is:

```
dict(my_list)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None}
```

Comment: You need to make sure each tuple has exactly two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following code. It checks for each tuple if a second element exists. If not `None` is used.

```
my_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2,3), ('c',)]

result = {x[0]: x[1] if len(x)>1 else None for x in my_list}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None}
```